# The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has n o enabled devices associated with it

Tags: psexec

I need to execute a script on an older Windows Server 2003 SE SP2 remotely from a different server using PSEXEC.  PSEXEC works on all other servers except this older one.  I get the following error:  The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has n o enabled devices associated with it.  Even D:\PSTools>psexec \ALA-SIEBI1P.corp.ad.wrs.com cmd throws the error.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more info, I would start by deleting the PSExec service on the remote host in question. PSExec actually creates a service on the remote host, and sometimes that service gets broken. Here's how to delete it, where %1 is replaced with the remote hostname:

```
sc \\%1 delete psexesvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -e option for psexec.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the PSEXEC service and run again.

```
Get-Service *psexec*
```

will show you the installed service.

```
Remove-Service PSEXESVC
```

will delete the service

afterwards...

```
psexec -s -i powershell
```

should execute as expected